# In MySQL, how to return one value from multiple tables matched on multiple fields

Tags: mysql

I have a table of invoice line items. Each line item can originate from one of several possible sources, e.g., client_id, entity_id, vendor_id, etc. Each one of these id's would match the primary key of another table, in which we would find the name and other info. I am trying to run a report of invoice line items. I want that report to include a value called "Source Name" for each line item that would display the corresponding name. So, if the source was the client it would show the client's name, if the source was the vendor it would show the vendor's name, etc. I would also like to be able to concatenate text to indicate whether it was the client, entity, vendor, etc.

Comment: At the very least provide some sample data (enough to cover your use cases) and the desired result.

Comment: I cant understand your tables and how you decide invoice pays by client or others!

Comment: I think I got it, but would still like to get other people's thoughts/ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for UNION.  If you have 2 tables you can use union to create one table

```
        SELECT * 
        FROM (
            SELECT client_id AS 'ID_FIELD', client_name AS 'NAME_FIELD', 'client' as 'TABLE_TYPE' FROM client_table
             UNION 
            SELECT vendor_id AS 'ID_FIELD', vendor_name AS 'NAME_FIELD', 'vendor' as 'TABLE_TYPE' FROM vendor_table
            ) AS t1

        WHERE t1.ID_FIELD = 'YOUR_VALUE_HERE'
```